# Wrap all methods of class that contain specific argument in Python

Tags: python

I have a class `Stuff` that has several methods, some of which have some argument, let's call it `argument_x`. For example:

```
class Stuff:
    def method_1(self, argument_x, **other_args):
        pass
    def method_2(self, argument_x, **other_args):
        pass
    def method_3(self, I_dont_have_argument_x):
        pass
```

Now I want to subclass this class wrapping all methods that have `argument_x` in the same way. For example if I were to proceed by hand I would do:

```
class StuffWithConstantX(Stuff):
    def __init__(self, argument_x_value):
        super().__init__()
        self._argument_x_value = argument_x_value
    def method_1(self, **other_args):
        super().method_1(argument_x=self._argument_x_value, **other_args)
    def method_2(self, **other_args):
        super().method_2(argument_x=self._argument_x_value, **other_args)
```

As `method_3` does not have `argument_x` I leave it unchanged.

Is it possible to automate this? How?

Comment: but wouldn't that break static type checkers? i.e. if you dynamically generate `method_1` for a new class, but don't expect argument_x as a required param for the function anymore.

Comment: This violates the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: @chepner yeah, I would just create a class that doesn't inherit from `Stuff`

Comment: How would you create such class, @juanpa.arrivillaga ? I want to have the same methods as `Stuff` but wrapping those that have the `argument_x` with a constant value.

Comment: Using compposition, not inheritance. so some `class Wrapper` that accepts an instance of `Stuff` e.g. `def __init__(stuff: Stuff, x: whatver) ->None: ...`

Comment: Anyway, it is possible to do this dynamically, probably, but are you sure you want to? And what exactly are the forms your methods can take when the have `argument_x`? will it always be `def foo(self, argument_x, **other_args)`? i.e. it will always be the second positional arugment, and the rest will be variadic keyword arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you might define this as a wrapper, rather than a subclass:

```
class Stuff:
    def method_1(self, argument_x, **other_args):
        print("method 1:", argument_x)
    def method_2(self, argument_x, **other_args):
        print("method 2:", argument_x)
    def method_3(self, i_dont_have_argument_x):
        print("method 3:", i_dont_have_argument_x)


class StuffWithConstantX:
    def __init__(self, argument_x_value) -> None:
        self._stuff = Stuff()
        self._argument_x = argument_x_value

    def __getattr__(self, __name: str):
        attr = getattr(self._stuff, __name)
        if not callable(attr):
            return attr
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return attr(argument_x=self._argument_x, *args, **kwargs)
            except TypeError:
                # Beware -- if there's a TypeError raised from attr itself,
                # it will get run twice before the caller sees the exception.
                # You can potentially work around this by closely inspecting
                # either the exception or the attr object itself.
                return attr(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped


stuff = StuffWithConstantX("foo")
stuff.method_1()
stuff.method_2()
stuff.method_3("bar")
```

```
method 1: foo
method 2: foo
method 3: bar
```

As noted in the comments, this code is more or less impossible to statically typecheck, and I would not recommend actually using this pattern unless you have a really good reason.

Comment: why the two leading underscores in `__name`?

Comment: For some reason that's what it defaults to.  I wasn't curious enough to look up the PEP that explains it.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean "defaults to?"

Comment: conventionally, I've seen `name` and `attr` as names for that first parameter, never `__name`

Comment: Look at the typeshed for `object`.  All of the dunder method params have dunder names.  Not sure why.  When you override a method in an IDE with a Python plugin, it will generally auto-completes the params with the names from the parent class.  I doubt it actually matters since I can't imagine anyone calling those functions with named args.

Comment: I mean, that's weird. That doesn't seem like a good reason, typeshed isn't really a good thing to emulate for style. Consider a simple search of the CPython code base for uses of `__getattr__`: https://github.com/python/cpython/search?p=1&q=__getattr__

Comment: Instead of the `try` `except`, could you have used the `if 'argument_x' in arg_names` as in [Charlie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73573522/8849755)? Would one have advantages over the other?

Comment: Yup, I think that'd work fine!  Not sure if there are any other gotchas with that method, but it at least wouldn't have the problem of getting a TypeError for some unrelated reason and retrying based on that.

Comment: *I would not recommend actually using this pattern unless you have a really good reason*, would it be better to proceed with the "by hand" implementation as in my original question?

Comment: Sorry for insisting, and I know this is not a university course but I am curious. What problems could bring up the impossibility to statically typecheck?

Comment: Static typechecking avoids a lot of other problems, so any time I have a solution that breaks static typechecking, I re-examine the problem and look for a better solution.  Sometimes there isn't one, but in the use case you describe, I would rather just have the extra work of hardcoding the variable than totally break static typechecking for the class, because of how much time typechecking saves me otherwise,

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way you could do it.

```py
import inspect
import functools

class StuffWithConstantX(Stuff):
    def __init__(self, argument_x_value):
        super().__init__()
        self._argument_x_value = argument_x_value

        for func_name, func in inspect.getmembers(Stuff, inspect.isfunction):
            arg_names = inspect.getfullargspec(func).args
            if 'argument_x' in arg_names:
                setattr(self, func_name, functools.partial(func, self=self, argument_x=self._argument_x_value))
```

Comment: This really should happen to the *class object*, don't do this at the instance level